# Understanding 一月分に余裕をもたせた

Tags: grammar, particle-に

> 最終チェックシークエンス完了。起動承認。瞬いて灯ったスクリーンに、見送りの整備クルー達が映る。半年を過ごしたぼろい隊舎と、半年世話になった整備クルー達。見えないと知りつつ頭を下げた。
>
> 一月分**に**余裕をもたせた物資と人数分の生活用品を満載した機動脚付き追加コンテナ五機を連結され、百足のようになったファイドが偵察隊の後ろに控える。

86─エイティシックス─
安里アサト

How should I understand the bold に? Does the bold に indicate 基準, as in "私に有利だ"? Does the phrase 一月分に余裕をもたせた mean "slightly more than a month’s worth of supply"?

Answer (score 5):

I think you understand the meaning correctly.

Regarding に, it can be understood as indicating the indirect object of the causative 余裕【よゆう】を持【も】たせる, like 彼【かれ】に話【はな】させる = let him speak.

- 余裕【よゆう】を持【も】つ *to have extra*
- 余裕【よゆう】を持【も】たせる *to let O have extra*
- 一【いっ】か月【げつ】分【ぶん】に余裕【よゆう】を持【も】たせる *to let a month's supply have extra*.

FYI, for comparison, 一【いっ】か月【げつ】分【ぶん】余裕【よゆう】を持【も】たせる (without に) would mean *to add extra of one month's worth*, that is, X + 1 month's worth instead of 1 month's worth + α.